# Replace "content" with the "image" in the Navigation bar

Tags: html, css

```css
.fa-home:before {
    content: "\f015";
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="/index.php" class="homelink">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to replace "content" Property "home" value in the navigation bar to corresponding image in the navigation bar.

Here is my css for "Content" property

```
.fa-home:before 
{
   content: "\f015";
}
```

So now i need to replace it with "header_home.png" image. Anyone give me information how to replace it with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this. You can control the aspect ratio of the image by using transform scale just like you want it to be. If I got your question correct.

```
.fa-home:before {
    content:url(/concrete5/application/images/header_home.png);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

You can also use this method to control the height and width

```
.fa-home:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(/concrete5/application/images/header_home.png);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr9g8fcg/1/)

Comment: @praveenkumarbeedanal can I see your code. Just fiddle it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fa-home:before {
  content: url(header_home.png); /*use correct path to image */
}
```

Comment: How can i set the size of the image ?

Comment: Actually this content property is in the another file so now i am overriding with your solution like this                                                                        .fa-home:before
{
 content:url(/concrete5/application/images/header_home.png) ! important;
} but it is not working.